# Change md-checkbox color

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-material

So it looks I can change the background-color of an empty `md-checkbox` by doing :

```
md-checkbox .md-icon {
background: red;
}
```

But I can't manage to change the background of a checked `md-checkbox`.
I tried  to play with `:checked`, `::before`, `::after`... But didn't succeed.

How should I proceed ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use theme class as well as `md-checked` class combination in order to define selector with higher specificity. For example:

```css
md-checkbox .md-icon {
    background: red;
}
md-checkbox.md-default-theme.md-checked .md-icon {
    background: orange;
}
```

And of course, avoid using `!important`, this is a sign that something is wrong with your styles.

Comment: Thanks, is there also a way to change the 'checking icon' color inside the box to make it suit the new color better ?

Comment: Try this rule: `md-checkbox.md-default-theme.md-checked .md-icon:after { border-color: green; }`. Or more generic: `md-checkbox.md-default-theme.md-checked .md-icon:after,
md-checkbox.md-default-theme:not([disabled]).md-checked .md-icon:after { border-color: green; }`.

Answer (score 6):

in new version added underscore ._md-icon:

```
md-checkbox.md-checked ._md-icon {
         background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: Good. Can you share me the link where they have mentioned about the changes?

Comment: Hi unfortunately,I have found this solution by myself after looking in there css files .